# Video game series where you set traps in a mansion

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Tip of my tongue, certain I saw this within the last year. It's a video game, I think on the Playstation consoles (maybe PS2?), likely originally Japanese, which had multiple sequels (some of which may not have been translated and officially released in the United States). You play the caretaker of a mansion (castle?), I think serving some malevolent being, and the goal of the game is to set traps that will ensnare visitors (intruders?). Kind of like a Dungeon Core or Tower Defense game, except that it's a more discrete number of targets, and I think you play the game from a first-person perspective rather than a more omniscient setup.

I believe there were a wide variety of traps that could be placed in various places on the walls, ceilings, and floors, and that it was possibly to "chain" the traps by having the effects usher your target from one trap to the next. I don't remember exactly how old it was, although if it dates back to the PS2, that puts it back a decade or two.

Comment: Since this has been answered, I would recommend giving [this Super Replay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkuwYGhUP3A) by GameInformer a watch! It's a full replay of Trapt, one of the games in the series you asked about. If you're into watching Let's Plays or anything, it's worth it :)

Comment: I was thinking [Spy vs Spy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_vs._Spy_(2005_video_game)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might this be Tecmo's ***[Deception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deception_(video_game_series))*** series...?

From Wikipedia:

> *Deception* is a series of console tactical role-playing games created and published by Tecmo for Sony's line of PlayStation consoles. They have an emphasis on passive combat via the use of traps. There are five games in the franchise.

- *[Tecmo's Deception: Invitation to Darkness](https://deceptionseries.fandom.com/wiki/Tecmo%27s_Deception:_Invitation_to_Darkness)* (1996)
- *[Kagero: Deception II](https://deceptionseries.fandom.com/wiki/Kagero:_Deception_II)* (1998)
- *[Deception III: Dark Delusion](https://deceptionseries.fandom.com/wiki/Deception_III:_Dark_Delusion)* (1999)
- *[Trapt](https://deceptionseries.fandom.com/wiki/Trapt)* (2005)
- *[Deception IV: Blood Ties](https://deceptionseries.fandom.com/wiki/Deception_IV:_Blood_Ties)* (2014)